# dpkg warning about '/etc/lsb-release' version number not starting with a digit

Tags: dpkg, lsb-release

I believe I spotted it during the upgrade from Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 to 16.04, but I know for sure that I spotted it just know during a `dist-upgrade`, I sometimes get this warning from `dpkg`:

```
dpkg: warning: version '/etc/lsb-release' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
```

The contents of the `/etc/lsb-release` file is:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

So I'm not entirely sure what the problem is and what (if anything) I should do about it... Is this a bug in the `lsb-release` file (somewhere where I haven't noticed) or is this a problem with `dpkg` or...?

Comment: Contents of my file are the exact same. I'm going to assume bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `dpkg` which has been reported here: [Bug #1597466](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1597466)